# My float items are linked to wrong entities

Tags: floats, hyperref, labels

I am using a `.sty` file from my university to prepare my dissertation. In this file, there is a float for "Algorithms" that I use to define

Algorithm 1, Algorithm 2, ...

My problem is that, no matter what the labels of my algorithms in the appendix section are, when I call them, their reference number is linked to algorithms in the main body, as opposed to the algorithms that they belong to.

After doing some research, I realized that there are parts of the `.sty` file that govern how the "List of Algorithms" are organized. This file creates a file with extension `.lom` that keeps all information about the algorithm list. In this file, the labels of appendix algorithms are linked to algorithms in the body! Please find below parts of the `.sty` file that talk about "List of Algorithms" rules. I am wondering if someone can help me with debugging these lines.

```
\def\listofalgorithms{%
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF ALGORITHMS}
\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\fi
\hbox{ }
\twoinmar
\centerline{\large\bf LIST OF ALGORITHMS}
\vspace{0.7in}
\begin{doublespace}
\@starttoc{lom}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
\addtocontents{lom}{\noindent\underline{\bf Algorithm}\hfill\rm\protect\newline}
\end{doublespace}
\pagestyle {empty}
}

\newcounter{algorithm}[chapter]
\def\thealgorithm{\@arabic\c@chapter.\@arabic\c@algorithm}
\def\fps@algorithm{tbp}
\def\ftype@algorithm{1}
\def\ext@algorithm{lom}
\def\fnum@algorithm{Algorithm\thealgorithm}
\def\algorithm{\@float{algorithm}}
\let\endalgorithm\end@float
\@namedef{algorithm*}{\@dblfloat{algorithm}}
\@namedef{endalgorithm*}{\end@dblfloat}
```

Comment: \appendix resets the chapter counter to one, but should change \thechapter to use \Alph instead of \arabic.  I can't test anything myself right now (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54806/miktex-package-manager-service-unavailable) but you might try \renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}

Comment: Where do you want me to add \renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}} ?
I added it to the preamble, but did not help. I have to say that I do not have any problems with my other floats like figures and tables.

Comment: You should add John's code immediately after the start of the appendix part of your document.

Comment: No it did not work. Please be reminded that my issue is not numbering. It is how the labels are linked to algorithms. The numbers are correct, but when I click on them a wrong algorithm shows up.

Comment: Please provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem, ideally with a link to the .sty file that you're required to use.

Comment: So, you are using the *hyperref* package, and your problem is that the link produced by a `\ref` command, when clicked, leads to a different algorithm than the one you intend (to an algorithm in the main text rather than to an algorithm in the appendices). Is this correct? If so, try `\newcommand*{\theHalgorithm}{\theHchapter.\arabic{algorithm}}` at the end of the preamble.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo. It solved my problem.

Also thank you Mico and John for your help. I was preparing MWE files that Gustavo solved my problem.

Comment: Actually, the solution proposed by @JohnKormylo should work too, if you apply it in the preamble—or better, if you modify the `.sty` file your university gave you: say `\def\thealgorithm{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}`, and also, I’d rather add, `\def\ftype@algorithm{4}` and `\def\fnum@algorithm{Algorithm \thealgorithm}` (note the space before `\thealgorithm`!).

Comment: To remove doubt, look at the aux file for the \newlabel commands.  The last entry should be the \hypertarget name.

Answer (score 1):

I created a partial MWE, but without access to the university `.sty` file I couldn't get `\listofalgorithms` to do anything.  Using `\label` and `\ref` worked as expected.  The only thing written to the `lom` file was the title line.  You should search for anything involving `\@writefile{lom}` or at least `\@writefile`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\twoinmar=\relax

\makeatletter
\def\listofalgorithms{%
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF ALGORITHMS}
\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\fi
\hbox{ }
\twoinmar
\centerline{\large\bf LIST OF ALGORITHMS}
\vspace{0.7in}
%\begin{doublespace}% also undefined
\@starttoc{lom}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
\addtocontents{lom}{\noindent\underline{\bf Algorithm}\hfill\rm\protect\newline}
%\end{doublespace}
\pagestyle {empty}
}

\newcounter{algorithm}[chapter]
\def\thealgorithm{\@arabic\c@chapter.\@arabic\c@algorithm}
\def\fps@algorithm{tbp}
\def\ftype@algorithm{1}
\def\ext@algorithm{lom}
\def\fnum@algorithm{Algorithm\thealgorithm}
\def\algorithm{\@float{algorithm}}
\let\endalgorithm\end@float
\@namedef{algorithm*}{\@dblfloat{algorithm}}
\@namedef{endalgorithm*}{\end@dblfloat}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}

\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms

\chapter{dummy}

\ref{first}

\ref{second}

\begin{algorithm}
\label{first}
first algorithm
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[1-4]

\appendix
\chapter{this space intentionally left blank}

\begin{algorithm}
\label{second}
second algorithm
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[5-8]
\end{document}
```